# Reset the login for another user with MS Graph accessed from the desktop

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using MS Graph in a desktop application so I am hosting a web browser in a form for the user to do their initial login.  This all works fine and I can fully use MS Graph.

The problem I have is if we need to use an account of a different user there does not seem to be a way to reset the login.  If you try to login again with the hosted web browser it will go right through and allow the same user.

The only way to reset it for another user seems to be to go into IE and delete the history/cache.  Then the login screen will ask a user to login again.  It seems a bit extreme to reset the cache.

So is this the only way to do this or is there something I can change in the MS Graph API call to tell it to reset?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can force re-authentication by added `prompt=login` to the [sign-in request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#send-the-sign-in-request):

> **Prompt** (optional)
>
> Indicates the type of user interaction that is required. The only valid values at this time are `login`, `none`, `select_account`, and `consent`.
>
> - `prompt=login` will force the user to enter their credentials on that request, negating single-sign on.
> - `prompt=none` is the opposite - it will ensure that the user isn't presented with any interactive prompt whatsoever. If the request can't be completed silently via single-sign on, the Microsoft identity platform endpoint will return an error.
> - `prompt=select_account` sends the user to an account picker where all of the accounts remembered in the session will appear.
> - `prompt=consent` will trigger the OAuth consent dialog after the user signs in, asking the user to grant permissions to the app.